# add and remove class when clicking on icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two types of icons:

icon-{payment_system_name} - grey 
icon-{payment_system_name}-active - active

This how look like my html:

```
<div id="vtb24-banking" class="inline-block space-sides-big">
   <input type="radio" name="payment_system" id="VTB24" value="VTB24">
   <label for="VTB24"><div class="icon icon-vtb24 pointer payment-logo"></div></label>
   <div id="vtb24-price" class="price"><span>500</span> руб.</div>
</div>
<div id="rsbbank-banking" class="inline-block space-sides-big">
   <input type="radio" name="payment_system" id="RSB" value="RSB">
   <label for="RSB"><div class="icon icon-rsbbank pointer payment-logo"></div></label>
   <div id="rsbbank-price" class="price"><span>500</span> руб.</div>
</div>
<div id="alfa-banking" class="inline-block space-sides-big">
   <input type="radio" name="payment_system" id="ALFACLICK" value="ALFACLICK">
   <label for="ALFACLICK"><div class="icon icon-alfa pointer payment-logo"></div></label>
   <div id="alfa-price" class="price"><span>500</span> руб.</div>
</div>
```

My task is - when clicking on payment system icon - it should be active, others grey.

My jquery code:

```
$('.payment-logo').click(function() {
   var paymentId = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id').split('-');
   $(this).addClass('icon-'+paymentId[0]+'-active');
});
```

but its only adding active icon class. How i can do the removing active classes from other payment systems?

Comment: you can go to http://jsfiddle.net/ and set up your project there so we can see how it behaves.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.payment-logo').click(function() {
    $('.payment-logo').each(function() {
        var paymentId = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id').split('-');
        $(this).removeClass('icon-'+paymentId[0]+'-active');
    });
    var paymentId = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id').split('-');
    $(this).addClass('icon-'+paymentId[0]+'-active');
});
```

Comment: the paymentId is different on every payment system

Answer (score 0):

**EleremoveClass("class name")** to remove any CSS class from element.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your approach is complicating the way you accomplish your target.

If you can customize a little the css classes, you can simplify the task this way:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hb88/)

CSS

```
.icon-alfa{
 /* your usual style */
}

.icon-alfa.is-active{
 /* the new style currently associated to icon-alfa-active */
}

/* and so for the other payment methods */

//then with JavaScript will be as simple as:

$('.payment-logo').on("click", function () {
   $('.payment-logo.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
   $(this).addClass('is-active');
});
```